# PGError: ERROR: column "p.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, redmine

I get an error with this query. Why? I don't understand :(

```
    SELECT p.name, p.id, SUM(hours) AS hours, SUM(logged_hours) AS logged_hours
    FROM (
        SELECT project_id, date, hours, null AS logged_hours
        FROM #{ScheduleEntry.table_name}
        WHERE user_id = #{User.current.id}
            AND date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
        UNION
        SELECT project_id, spent_on AS date, null AS hours, sum(#{TimeEntry.table_name}.hours) AS logged_hours
        FROM #{TimeEntry.table_name}
        WHERE user_id = #{User.current.id}
            AND spent_on BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
        GROUP BY project_id, date
    ) AS results
    LEFT JOIN #{Project.table_name} AS p ON p.id = results.project_id
    GROUP BY project_id
```

Comment: What do you want that query to return?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `GROUP BY project_id` to `GROUP BY p.name,p.id`

[The docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) say:

> When `GROUP BY` is present, it is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column.

Comment: But will it give me the same results??

Comment: It does not give the same results. Instead of grouping it by `project_id`, it will group it by `p,name` and than by `p.id`. Not the same result.