# Rails PG GroupingError column must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

there are a few topics about this already with accepted answers but I couldn't figure out a solution based on those:
Eg:

- [Ruby on Rails: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433016/ruby-on-rails-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-fun)
- [GroupingError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942477/groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an)
- [PGError: ERROR: column "p.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786768/pgerror-error-column-p-name-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in?rq=1)

My query is:

```
Idea.unscoped.joins('inner join likes on ideas.id = likes.likeable_id').
select('likes.id, COUNT(*) AS like_count, ideas.id, ideas.title, ideas.intro, likeable_id').
group('likeable_id').
order('like_count DESC')
```

This is fine in development with sqlite but breaks on heroku with PostgreSQL.

The error is:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "likes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

If I put likes.id in my group by then the results make no sense. Tried to put group before select but doesn't help. I even tried to take the query into two parts. No joy. :(

Any suggestions appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to select `likes.id` in the first place. I see that you basically want the `like_count` for each Idea; I don't see the point in selecting `likes.id`. Also, when you already have the `ideas.id`, I don't see why you would want to get the value of `likes.likeable_id` since they'll both be equal. :/

Anyway, the problem is since you're grouping by `likeable_id` (basically `ideas.id`), you can't "select" `likes.id` since they would be "lost" by the grouping.

I suppose SQLite is lax about this. I imagine it wouldn't group things properly.

ANYWAY(2) =>

Let me propose a cleaner solution.

```
# model
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  # to save you the effort of specifying the join-conditions
  has_many :likes, foreign_key: :likeable_id
end

# in your code elsewhere
ideas = \
  Idea.
  joins(:likes).
  group("ideas.id").
  select("COUNT(likes.id) AS like_count, ideas.id, ideas.title, ideas.intro").
  order("like_count DESC")
```

If you still want to get the IDs of likes for each item, then after the above, here's what you could do:

```
grouped_like_ids = \
  Like.
  select(:id, :likeable_id).
  each_with_object({}) do |like, hash|
    (hash[like.likeable_id] ||= []) << like.id
  end

ideas.each do |idea|
  # selected previously:
  idea.like_count
  idea.id
  idea.title
  idea.intro

  # from the hash
  like_ids = grouped_like_ids[idea.id] || []
end
```

Other readers: I'd be very interested in a "clean" one-query non-sub-query solution. Let me know in the comments if you leave a response. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that was quick! Forgot to add that I just started web dev 1.5month ago.

Comment: [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) can aggregate each individual id to an array (I think ruby supports PostgreSQL arrays, but I'm not sure) -- anyway, `string_agg()` could be used, if arrays are not supported in RoR

Comment: @pozs, note that we need a solution that'll work in SQLite too. The OP is using SQLite in development.

Comment: @Humza yeah, if a single query needed to handle both vendors, that won't help. But `string_agg()` works like SQLite's `group_concat()`, if a varying query is acceptable by OP.

Comment: I don't know man. `Rails.env.production? ? postgres_function : (Rails.env.development? ? sqlite_function : something_else)` looks really messy. Thanks for the input though.